# Log power rules - error in thinking

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, logarithms, absolute-value

I am trying manipulate an equation with logs, and I am 99% sure that there is something going wrong in my thinking.

I started of with seomthing like this:

$-\log Ae^x$

using log rule $\log AB = \log A + \log B$

(1)
$-(\log A + \log e^x)=$

(2)$-\log A - \log e^x=$

(3)$-\log A + \log e^{-x}=$

(4)$-\log A e^{-x}$

which is clearly wrong, I can see that to, but I cannot see where my algebra is failing me, where am I missing the necessary brackets?

Comment: $(1)$ of course.

Comment: Far as I can tell the only place you actually go wrong is from (3) to (4); I'm not sure what rule you're trying to apply there.

Comment: forgot the A - added it now

Comment: @SandraK: Then, the part from (3) to (4) is wrong. It should be $-\log A+\log{e^{-x}}=-\log A-(-1)\log{e^{-x}}=-\log A-\log{e^x}$$=-(\log A+\log{e^x})=-\log{Ae^x}$ for $A\gt 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer is $(1)$.

Also, $(3)$ is valid.

I think your rule is wrong.

It should be $$\log{AB}=\log|A|+\log|B|,$$
otherwise $$\log4=\log((-2)(-2))=\log(-2)+\log(-2),$$
which is delirium.

Comment: Thanks alot - thats what I was looking for!

Comment: @SandraK You are welcome!